# Don't know what I am doing wrong in below code in twig for counter

Tags: twig

Counter always printing 1

```
{% if label_hidden %}
    {% if multiple %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ item.content }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        /* counter set below for incriment */
        {% set counter = 1 %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ counter }}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if counter == 2 %}
                <div class="spectra-promo col-md-6 spectra-offer-info">
                <h3>{{ item.content }}</h3>
            {% endif %}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if counter == 3 %}
                <h5>{{ item.content }}</h5>
                <div class="choose-offer">
                <div class="left-sec">
            {% endif %}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if counter == 4 %}
                <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
                <div class="right-sec">
                <p><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-                       hidden="true"></i></a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            /* counter increment below */
            {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Counter is print 1 , not increment

Comment: @t-n-y what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are the /* condition check*/ you put in your code ? and why are you closing html tags in other if condition ??

Comment: @t-n-y I am just breaking the html tag, but I don't this is the problem for printing 1

Comment: probably not, but i try to understand your code ... i think you can find a better solution for this, cause it s not very good

Comment: I know it's not very good solution. But I don't have better solution .

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Did it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a counter, you can directly use the [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% if label_hidden %}
    {% if multiple %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ item.content }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ loop.index }}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if loop.index == 2 %}
                <div class="spectra-promo col-md-6 spectra-offer-info">
                <h3>{{ item.content }}</h3>
            {% endif %}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if loop.index == 3 %}
                <h5>{{ item.content }}</h5>
                <div class="choose-offer">
                <div class="left-sec">
            {% endif %}

            /* condition  check*/
            {% if loop.index == 4 %}
                <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
                <div class="right-sec">
                <p><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-                       hidden="true"></i></a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```